# Camel splitter with custom bean in spring xml

Tags: apache-camel

I am using following xml configuration for defining a custom bean for splitter.

```
  <camel:split stopOnException="true">
      <camel:method bean="splitterBean" method="split" /> 
       <camel:to ref="sodSQLEndPoint"/>
    </camel:split>

 <bean id="splitterBean" class="com.processor.SodFundListSplitter" />
```

It doesn't run and gives an error:

12:31:28.770 [main] WARN  org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper - Cannot find class: splitterBean.

If I use body instead of the custome bean, it works fine. Can anyone please tell me if there is anything extra to be done for allowing custom bean with splitter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ref instead of bean

```
<camel:split stopOnException="true">
   <camel:method ref="splitterBean" method="split" /> 
   <camel:to ref="sodSQLEndPoint"/>
</camel:split>
```

Comment: Even after changing it to Ref does not work. I get same error saying                                                                14:53:19.445 [main] WARN  org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper - Cannot find class: splitterBean